# Closure editor. Set full page code

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I'm playing with closure editor - ivestigating does it fit to my(not my, but client's) requirements. And can't discover, next thing:
Does editor have a possibility to receive the complete html into itself, I want to set into it, something like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />
 </head>
 <body>....</body>
</html>
```

but simple setHtml() method moves everything from head section to body..
Please advise, what can be done here?